# Are /ɪnˈfɪə/ or /ɪnˈfirəns/ actually used?

Tags: pronunciation

I had a debate with a non-native speaker who pronounced

- *infer* as **/ɪnˈfɪə/**; rhymes with *career*
- *inference* as **/ɪnˈfirəns/**; rhymes with *clearance;* stress on the second syllable

and claimed that this pronunciation was common (in particular in American English), though they admitted that it’s not the only possible option.

However, all sources I consulted listed:

- *infer* as **/ɪnˈfɜː/** or similar; rhymes with *refer*
  [¹](//dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/infer)
  [²](//www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/infer)
  [³](//www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/infer)
  [⁴](//www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infer)
  [⁵](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infer#Pronunciation)
- *inference* as **/ˈɪnfərəns/** or similar; rhymes with *conference;* stress on the first syllable
  [¹](//dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/inference)
  [²](//www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inference)
  [³](//www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/inference)
  [⁴](//www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inference)

On the other hand, I see no way how the first pair of pronunciation should emerge from a mistake: All orthographically similar words I can think of (*refer(ence), defer(ence), prefer(ence), confer(ence), circumference*) are pronounced in a consistently different manner and I can’t even think of any word that could be used as a blueprint for this pronunciation. This is a hint (but nothing more) that these pronunciations may be real.

Therefore I am asking: Did I miss something and **do any native speakers actually use the first pair of pronunciations?**

Comment: I speak AmE, and I don't believe I have ever heard these pronunciations.

Comment: The word *interference* is orthographically similar to *inference*, and could be used as a blueprint for its incorrect pronunciation.

Comment: The _inference_-pronunciation I can actually undertand, following Peter Shor's point. But why anyone would pronounce _-fer_ as _-fɪə_ is beyond me.

Comment: @oerkelens: once you're started pronouncing *inference* as /ɪnˈfirəns/, wouldn't it be natural to pronounce *infer* as /ɪnˈfɪə/.

Comment: I'm guessing this non-standard pronunciation arose through conflation with ***interfere, interference*** (the orthographic route, not a mishearing). If this was a common mistake for certain nns to make, it might be worth addressing it on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but I can't see the point of it here on ELU.

Comment: I'm positive I've heard people (including native speakers) say _inference_, but I've never heard anyone, native or non-native, say _infere_ (as it were).

Comment: I have heard in-FURR-ence (not in-FEAR-ence) to clarify it or differentiate it (from difference?).  The word inference does not come out clearly and distinctly.  Similarly, native speakers often contrast 'sixty' with 'six-TEEN.'  Otherwise, a 'SIX-teen sixty six' date accents the SIX.

Comment: Aside from "interference" (mentioned by Peter Shor and FumbleFingers), the word "perseverance" is now usually pronounced with a stressed penult "long e", by analogy with the verb "persevere". The OED says that both used to have pronunciations with the stress on the second syllable. I don't know of any evidence that native speakers have ever used a pronunciation like /ɪnˈfɪə/, though.

Comment: @herisson I won’t say it’s impossible, but like you, I cannot recall **ever** hearing *infer* pronounced with the "long-i" /i/ FLEECE vowel of *fear*, only with the normal NURSE vowel. Otherwise that would make near rhymes of *now infer* and *now in fear* — and, with the quite common pre-sonorant syllabic breaking so often heard everywhere, even of *now I’ll see her* **[ˌnawajəlˈsijəɹ]**. But maybe there are accents from the American Deep South or Southeast that draw all those out and add new diphthongs and/or syllables like that?